# Cache Evict issue with @Cacheable parameterless method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm trying to implement Spring caching in a Spring Boot RESTful service. This is the caching code for the getAllBlogs() and getBlogById() methods.

```
@Cacheable(value="allblogcache")
@Override
public List<Blog> getAllBlogs() {
    System.out.println("******* "+ blogRepository.findAll().toString());
    return (List<Blog>) blogRepository.findAll();

}

@Cacheable(value="blogcache", key = "#blogId")
@Override
public Blog getBlogById(int blogId) {
    Blog retrievedBlog = null;
    retrievedBlog = blogRepository.findById(blogId).get();
    return retrievedBlog;
}
```

In the saveBlog method I want to evict the cache and have used the following code.

```
 @Caching(evict = {
        @CacheEvict(value="allblogcache"),
        @CacheEvict(value="blogcache", key = "#blog.blogId")
  })
  @Override
  public Blog saveBlog(Blog blog) {
    return blogRepository.save(blog);
  }
```

On running, I did the following using Postman:

1. Saved two blogs. Both blogs are getting saved to the database.
2. called get All blogs. Both the saved blogs are returned.
3. Saved a new blog. Here I assume the cache has been evicted.
4. I called get All blogs. However, only two blogs are getting returned. This 
   means the blogs are returned from the old cache. It didn't get evicted by the
   call to the third save.

The github repo is at https://github.com/ximanta/spring-cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `allEntries = true` attribute if you're evicting caches without specifying a key (see [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html#allEntries--)).

In your case, it would be `@CacheEvict(value="allblogcache", allEntries = true)`

P.S. tested it and managed to make it work. PR: https://github.com/ximanta/spring-cache/pull/1

Comment: Thanks. This solved :) One opinion from you. In the test for getAllBlogs(), I called save() on service twice and then called getAllBlogs() on service multiple times. When verifying the mock repository interactions, I found two interactions happened with the repository mock. verify(blogRepository, times(2)).findAll();
I was expecting 1. Bcause the first time getAll() would retrieve from the database and from second time onwards, from cache. But it apperas, it retrieved from database twice, and from third call onwards from cache. I pushed the code. What is your view on this?

Comment: That's because you call `findAll()` method [twice](https://github.com/ximanta/spring-cache/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackroute/service/BlogServiceImpl.java#L43) inside `getAllBlogs()`

Comment: @amsagar that is the point I'm raising. The second findAll() should have returned from the cache instead of calling the repository.

Comment: That's not correct - you marked `getAllBlogs()` as cacheable, so if it's called somewhere outside, it should be executed only once. That does not affect its inner calls (e.g., `blogRepository.findAll()` calls).

Answer (score 0):

It throw exception because you use wrong key expression:

```
@Caching(evict = {
    @CacheEvict(value="allblogcache"),
    @CacheEvict(value="blogcache", key = "#blogId")
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~ => Refer to parameter blogId but not found
})
public Blog saveBlog(Blog blog)
```

The correct expression is:

```
@Caching(evict = {
    @CacheEvict(value="allblogcache"),
    @CacheEvict(value="blogcache", key = "#blog.id") // Assume that the property for blog ID is "id"
})
public Blog saveBlog(Blog blog)
```

Comment: Thanks Manh. I was able to fix the error based on your suggestion, but the core issue of cache eviction still remains. I have edited the question. Please do have a look and suggest.